# Which word is stressed in this sentence “Sometimes you don't even know…” of the below video?

Tags: word-stress, intonation

Some told me **different word stresses in a sentence conveys different meanings**. So I'm learning to find out **where the stress is**.

If the word is said **clearly, powerfully and highest in pitch**, then it's easy to find out it's the word the speaker wanna emphasize. However, there were some cases, in the same sentence, the word - that I thought it might be the main stress of the sentence - was said in the **highest pitch but sound very weak and less powerful than the lower pitch** (for example, there was a case in which the word "really" in "really gorgeous" was said in higher pitch than "gorgeous" but less powerful). So that causes me difficulty to find out which word the speaker want to stress, and then I can't fully understand what they mean.

---

Which word is stressed in this sentence in [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqQAlZcIf4Y&feature=youtu.be&t=733)?

I take the above video to make it clear for you to understand what I'm saying. In that video I hear "sometimes" was said clearly and was in the highest pitch, but I think the speaker wanted to spilt "sometimes" and "you don't even know..." into 2 parts and each part has it's own stress. So I don't care about "sometimes", I turn my attention to "you don't even know..." and question myself - which word did the speaker want to emphasize?. Then it's confusing when I hear "**don't ev**..." was said in **higher pitches** than "know", but "**know**" was **drawled longer** than "don't even".

So Which word, "**sometimes**", "**don't**", "**even**" or "**know**", did the speaker stress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speaker is emphasizing  **"know"** by using **"don't even"**